# Phpmyadmin shows blank page to login form

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin to my machine.

Oracle Machine:
Ubuntu 20.04
Apache 2
PHP 7.4
VM.Standard.A1.Flex
OCPU count: 4
Network bandwidth (Gbps): 4
Memory (GB): 24

entering the site: http://IP_ADDRES/phpmyadmin I see a blank page.
[image: blank]

Chrome console:

[image: chrome console]

Apache 2 error logs:

```
[Sun Nov 21 12:38:13.974891 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 33222] [client 83.144.89.150:63846] PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: unrecognised compile-time option bit(s) at offset 0 in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Sanitize.php on line 200
[Sun Nov 21 12:38:13.974897 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 33222] [client 83.144.89.150:63846] PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: unrecognised compile-time option bit(s) at offset 0 in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Sanitize.php on line 206
```

Please help.

Comment: This is for dba or better, server fault.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch 5.1.1

Comment: Are there any hints in the webserver error log?